# unit test and mock a repository

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, junit4

I want to inquire how to mock a repository class and make a unit test for its functions.

- Repository Class

```
class RequestRepository {

    /** suspend function to get the result of token request from API*/
    suspend fun getToken(userLoginModel: UserLoginModel): Response<TokenResponse> {
        return ApiService.APILogin.getToken(userLoginModel)
    }

    // many more functions to come here
    …
}
```

- I tried this test function but it did not work

```
class LoginUnitTest {
    private var repositoryTest = RequestRepository()
    private var userLoginModelTest = Mockito.mock(UserLoginModel::class.java)

    @Test
    suspend fun login_with_correct_login_and_password() {
        userLoginModelTest.email = "wrong mail"
        userLoginModelTest.password = "wrong password"

        var resultTest: Boolean = repositoryTest.getToken(userLoginModelTest).isSuccessful
        if (resultTest)
            assert(resultTest) { " we have issue in this function  " }
        else
            assert(resultTest) { " we are good " }
        
    }
}
```

- I recieved this error message:

```
org.junit.runners.model.InvalidTestClassError: Invalid test class 'fr.mastergime.moez.arkindex.LoginUnitTest':
  1. Method login_with_correct_login_and_password() should be void
  2. Method login_with_correct_login_and_password should have no parameters

    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.validate(ParentRunner.java:525)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:102)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.JUnit4.<init>(JUnit4.java:23)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.JUnit4Builder.runnerForClass(JUnit4Builder.java:10)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:70)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:37)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:70)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.createRunner(ClassRequest.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.MemoizingRequest.getRunner(MemoizingRequest.java:19)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.FilterRequest.getRunner(FilterRequest.java:36)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:49)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper.main(CommandLineWrapper.java:64)
```

Comment: i tried with function but not work

Comment: You had a question, and it got answered, and the way to go now is to accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I notice four things here:

- You *ask* for mocking of the repository, but instead mock the model class that you do not show.
- You use JUnit 4, which is, well, ancient. Please use JUnit 5 Jupiter. (Or some Kotlin-specific framework.)
- You use Mockito, which is not bad in general. For Kotlin, however, you should consider [MockK](https://github.com/mockk/mockk), which can mock some of the things that are particular to Kotlin (like suspend-functions).

Finally, the real reason why you setup fails: You cannot have a `suspend`-function as a test method in JUnit. Remove the `suspend` keyword for `login_with_correct_login_and_password`.

Comment: thank you for answering me but stuck with it unit test can you exempel for my case am stuck until now idk how do it is my first time using unit test for my code  for exempel my function getPages how can i test it ? and thank you

Comment: I do no understand your comment, I’m sorry. But anyway: You cannot use `suspend` here. Your problem is not related to mocking.